# Set custom action bar title text view to behave as default one

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have set for my activity a custom layout for the action bar, which includes a TextView that should act as the title TextView present in the default action bar layout. My question is: how do I get the system to identify the title TextView with mine? I wonder if it is possible to set my TextView so that Android would update its text value to correspond the activity title, just like it would do with a default layout action bar.